# Background image z-index issue with image element

Tags: html, css, z-index

I wanna make overlay background image to image. the code is [here](http://codepen.io/vefali/pen/aoisx).
How can I put background image over img element?

my html is;

```
<div id="sidebar">
        <div class="editor-select">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mh3noQH.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my css is;

```
  #sidebar{
  width: 344px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/BQc7nYP.png") no-repeat top right !important;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.editor-select{
  width: 350px;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
}

.editor-select>img{
      width: 320px;
    height: 160px;
   z-index : -1;
}
```

Comment: Change the #sidebar's position to absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Your `img` element is contained within the `#sidebar` element, which effectively makes the `img` element *on top of* the `#sidebar` element. You cannot position a parent element on top of its child.

## Pure CSS Solution

What you can do, however, is use a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content) (`:before` or `:after`), positioned on top of your `img` element (which I've offset by 6px on all 4 sides to allow the image to overlap properly):

```css
.editor-select:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: -6px;
      left: -6px;
      height: 172px;
      width: 332px;
      background: url("http://i.imgur.com/BQc7nYP.png") no-repeat top right
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sDGpz).

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a background for a given element above the element contents .... You'll need to make some adjustments to your markup.

I forked your pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ipmDv

This is your new HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mh3noQH.jpg" alt="resim"/>
    </div>
```

And your new CSS:

```
 #sidebar{
  width: 344px;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.overlay{
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1000;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/BQc7nYP.png") no-repeat top right !important;
  top:0px;
  right:25px;
}
```